# Image file location (on hard drive) - how to find it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I first opened Photoshop and it had a lesson in it. There were already some photos provided.

[image]

How do I find this image on my disc? I want to open it outside of Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the tab with the filename and select *Reveal in Explorer* (Windows) or *Reveal in Finder* (Mac).

Comment: Same on a Mac.. except "Reveal in Finder"

Answer (score 1):

Save it as a new file and you will be able to find the image to your chosen save location.